# How do I map (local) to a non-standard named SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 (SQL Server 2005 was already installed) on my XP box and name the local instance of the database so that it wouldn't clash with SQL Server 2005.

Now I want to change the mapping of (local) from SQL Server 2005 to my non-standard named SQL Server 2008 instance. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid Mladen is correct.

- You can move the db's from one
  instance to another using
  attach/detach or backup/restore.
- You can transfer all logins (if
  needed) with [this method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133).
- You can move SQL Agent scripts by
  right-clicking on them on the existing server and selecting
  *generate script* then running that
  script on the new server.

.

You will have to do the following (Assuming you'd like to make 2008 your default instance):

1. Install 2005 named instance.
2. Move the default to the named using above method.
3. Uninstall 2005 default instance.
4. Install 2008 default instance.
5. Move the named to the default using above method.
6. Uninstall 2008 named instance.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

nope. you'll have to reinstall both.

Comment: This is correct. You can't rename an instance in situ.

It may not be what you want to hear, but it's what happens.

Answer (score -2):

Create an alias in the sql config manager.  Enable named pipes for your instance with surface area config and you will be in business.

Comment: An alias only masks the issue for the local machine.
Named pipes is a backwards step too.

Comment: It worked for me.  He didn't state he was concerned about external clients, so no biggy.